# How to get the probability a prediction is correct from a binary classifier

Tags: classification, model, tensorflow, keras, image-processing

I have an image binary classifier that where class a = 0 and class b = 1

When I receive a prediction of a single image, is working out the probability that the prediction is correct as simple as:

a:  0 = 100%, 0.25 = 50%, 0.5  = 0%

b:  1 = 100%, 0.75 = 50%, 0.5  = 0%

?

Comment: What do the numbers to the left of your equality signs refer to? And what kind of prediction do you have ("hard" classifications, or probabilistic predictions)? In general, your question can't be answered, simply because your probabilistic classifier may be miscalibrated, and "hard" classifications will depend on thresholds of probabilistic classifiers or on other parameters.

Comment: The numbers are the values of output of the prediction. The formula that I think should give the probability of the prediction being right is -(classification-0.5)*200 for a
and(classification-0.5)*200 for b.

Comment: You would do well to abandon the idea of forced-choice classification and instead use a probability model.  Then for an item for which you estimate the probability to be p, your probability of being wrong in acting as if Y=1 will occur is by definition 1-p.

Comment: @FrankHarrell If the predictions are calibrated

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(Correct\vert Category=K) = \dfrac{
P(Category=K\vert Correct)P(Correct)
}{
P(Category=K)
}
$$

$P(Correct)$ is the accuracy. $P(Category=K)$ is how many times you predict category $K$ out of the total number of predictions you make.

For $P(Category=K\vert Correct)$, restrict your predictions to the correct predictions. Then look at what fraction of those are predicted to be $K$.

Unfortunately, you need the true labels to calculate $P(Category=K\vert Correct)$, so you cannot do this in the setting where you're making predictions on data where you truly do not know the labels (e.g., Siri or Alexa doing speech recognition on sentences that have never before been spoken). When you do have the labels (such as in a test set), however, this is related to the positive and negative predictive values, which tell you the probability of a case being positive or negative ($1$ or $0$ in standard categorical encoding) given a prediction of positive or negative, respectively.

But all of this assumes that you're making a categorical prediction. The neural network models you're using return probability values, not categories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I feel like I'm out of my depth here... The best way I have of explaining is at the bottom here - https://keras.io/examples/vision/xray_classification_with_tpus/#predict-and-evaluate-results . When it says 'This image is 52.81 percent PNEUMONIA' isn't that the chances of the prediction being correct?

Comment: @daveyb That's just the predicted probability of the image depicting pneumonia. For all you know, the model could be terrible and give predicted probability values that are unrelated to reality. As an analogy, if some person told you that you had a $52.81\%$ chance of having pneumonia but a trained doctor told you that you had a $95\%$ chance of having pneumonia, would you believe that $52.81$?